# Slow attribute table loading after join table via custom plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-joins

I am new to QGIS and I am currently learning pyqgis.
My problem is I tried to create a custom plugin to join csv and shapefile with 20,000+ features. I was successful in joining csv and shapefile via custom plugin that I created using this code.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import qgis
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorJoinInfo

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    # Change to your shapefile name
    if layer.name() == "MyShapefile":
        qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        shp = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    # Change to your csv name
    if layer.name() == "MyDatabase":
        qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        csv = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# Set up join parameters
shpField='PIN'
csvField='UPIN'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = csv.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = csvField
joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField
shp.addJoin(joinObject)
```

But when i try to open the attribute table it loads very slow and counting features by 8/10/15 at max. But when I join table using properties>join of shapefile and check the "cache data in virtual memory" my attributes loads perfectly fine even if I have 20,000 features.

My question is how can I make the loading of attribute table faster like in joining via properties>join using a custom plugin?

I am using QGIS 2.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `joinObject.memoryCache = True` before you initiate the join:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import qgis
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorJoinInfo

shp = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( "MyShapefile" )[0]
csv = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( "MyDatabase" )[0]

# Set up join parameters
shpField='PIN'
csvField='UPIN'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = csv.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = csvField
joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField
joinObject.memoryCache = True
shp.addJoin(joinObject)
# shp.createJoinCaches()
```

Comment: will try it now sir Jospeh. Thank you for replying. Godbless you. :)

Comment: Hi Sir Joseph,
I tried adding joinObject.memoryCache = True but still with no luck.. the attribute table still loads very slow counting by 8/10/15. I tried using it thru Macro and my Custom Join Plugin.

Thank you and more power.

Comment: No need to thank me for replying =). Does it work if you do it in the **Python Console**?

Comment: It works in Python Console but still loading the attribute table by 8/10/15 after table join. :(

Comment: After you type it in the python console, is the memory cache ticked in the **Joins** properties?

Comment: Yes sir, It is ticked in the Joins properties.

Comment: Strange, I cannot replicate your issue and I have >100k features with about 3 dozen fields. You could try adding `shp.createJoinCaches()` after `shp.addJoin(joinObject)`.

Comment: And how long does it take to load your attribute table with >100k features? 
If possible, may I look into your script? Maybe I can find something out from it.. Thank you and Godbless Sir Joseph.

Comment: It takes a few seconds thanks to the memory cache. I asked a _somewhat related_ question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190683/why-does-joining-all-layers-in-a-group-not-work) where my layers did not load both visually and the attribute table. The code was used in a plugin. I wonder why it is still slow for you...I also simplified your code a bit =)

Comment: well i think I figured it out.. as you can see in my script UPIN is in all caps while in my csv it should be small letters upin i changed it in the code and now it loads in an instant. :) Thank you for the support! :) hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: I think this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCmuATH2yzo) says it all...and most welcome :)

Comment: the video says it all! hahahahahah!